# Using Selenium Records for Jmeter Web Driver Sampler

Tags: selenium, webdriver, jmeter

I am trying to convert the code I recorded with selenium

```
try {
  assertEquals("", driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).getAttribute("value"));
} catch (Error e) {
  verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
```

to be used in the Web Driver Sampler in Jmeter. That's what I have so far but it doesn't work because the line with `pkg.By.xpath` is wrong. `EcmaError: ReferenceError: "pkg" is not defined.`
So pkg doesn't seem to work. The problem is, I can't find any good documentation for the jmeter web driver sample besides [this one](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/source/browse/wiki/WebDriverSampler.wiki?spec=svn2368&r=2368) which just shows me a very basic example.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get('http://google.com.au')


var q=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@name='q']"))
q.sendKeys("Hallo")




WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found a way better documentation, no idea why this didn't came up in the search.
[This Documentation](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=WebDriverSampler) pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would provide you another piece of code that I found very helpful for me:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://duckduckgo.com')
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_form_input_homepage'))
searchField.click()
searchField.sendKeys(['blazemeter'])
var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_button_homepage'))
button.click()
var link = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.ByCssSelector('#r1-0 > div.links_main > h2 > a.large > b'))
link.click()
WDS.log.info(WDS.name + ' has logged an entry');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

[Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) will give you more detalization on it.